# UTL_SMTP Package Error while sending an email

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have created a procedure which is written below:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 26)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);
  UTL_SMTP.data(l_mail_conn, p_message);
  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
```

After running the procedure,I am getting an error:-

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [psdnop-1], [604], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 17
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 246
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 115
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 138
ORA-06512: at "APPS.SEND_MAIL", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Please help.

Comment: `ORA-0600` errors are special. Is this a production environment?

Comment: @mmmmmpie No.It is a test instance

Comment: Ok. [`ORA-600`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600) <-- please read this, then you should consider opening an SR to troubleshoot.

Comment: Do you have oracle wallet in your database application ???

Comment: @mmmmmpie-I got a solution regarding this in Oracle metalink Doc ID 1590304.1 but still I am unable to resolve it.

Comment: @psaraj12-No as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

In my application it looks (and works) like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_subject   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_domain IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
    PRIORITY_HIGH           CONSTANT INTEGER := 1;
    PRIORITY_NORMAL         CONSTANT INTEGER := 3;
    PRIORITY_LOW            CONSTANT INTEGER := 5;
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
    l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
    UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_domain);
    UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
    UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);  
    UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: <'||p_from||'>'||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: <'||p_to||'>'||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: '||p_subject||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'X-Priority: '||PRIORITY_NORMAL||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'||UTL_TCP.CRLF );
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(p_message));
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);
    UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
```

Note, don't miss the `UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);` lines.

BTW, default TCP port for SMTP is 25 not 26.

Comment: @Wernfried-I got a solution regarding this in Oracle metalink Doc ID 1590304.1 but still I am unable to resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you created ACL for network access? if not then check the following:

First run the below command by changing yourmailserver with your mail server and after a space specify port number.

```
alter system set smtp_out_server = 'yourmailserver yourport' scope=both;

-- change the yourmailserver with your mail server and after a space specify port number.

Then run below script in Sys user but before running this script modify the youruser and yourmailserver in script.

--RUN IN SYS USER FOR ACL PRIVILEGE FOR ORACLE 11G
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- "Set define off" turns off substitution variables. 
Set define off; 

--- RUN IN SYS USER ---

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mailserver_acl(
aacl varchar2,
acomment varchar2,
aprincipal varchar2,
aisgrant boolean,
aprivilege varchar2,
aserver varchar2,
aport number)
Is
BEGIN 
BEGIN
Dbms_Network_Acl_Admin.DROP_ACL(aacl);
Dbms_Output.put_Line('ACL dropped.....');
EXCEPTION
When Others Then
Dbms_Output.put_Line('Error dropping ACL: '||aacl);
Dbms_Output.put_Line(SQLERRM);
END;
BEGIN
Dbms_Network_Acl_Admin.CREATE_ACL(aacl,acomment,aprincipal,aisgrant,aprivilege);
Dbms_Output.put_Line('ACL created.....');
EXCEPTION
When Others Then
Dbms_Output.put_Line('Error creating ACL: '||aacl);
Dbms_Output.put_Line(SQLERRM);
END; 
BEGIN
Dbms_Network_Acl_Admin.ASSIGN_ACL(aacl,aserver,aport);
Dbms_Output.put_Line('ACL assigned.....'); 
EXCEPTION
When Others Then
Dbms_Output.put_Line('Error assigning ACL: '||aacl);
Dbms_Output.put_Line(SQLERRM);
END; 
COMMIT;
Dbms_Output.put_Line('ACL commited.....');
END;
/

-- replace youruser with your user name and yourmailserver and yourport with your values:

BEGIN
mailserver_acl(
'mailserver_acl.xml',
'ACL for used Email Server to connect',
'YourUser',
TRUE,
'connect',
'YourMailServer',
YourPort); 
END;
/
```

Comment: Incorrect ACL configuration will not throw an `ORA-0600` it will throw an `ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)` error. He is receiving a kernel error from the database.